# Kibana truncating data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

I have ELK setup as below :-

Elasticsearch - 6.3
logstash - 6.3
kibana - 6.3

Data is loaded properly in elasticsearch..but kibana doesn;t show in same way.  For prodver field , its values is 4.99.6 but in Kibana its shows as 4.99

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "amp_index-2018-1jul-5jul",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "3167130661",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2018-07-16T15:11:19.726Z",
      "country": "US",
      "browserver": "11.1",
      "prodver": "4.99.6",
      "@version": "1",
      "city": "DENVER",
      "startTime": "2018-07-02T23:29:55.000Z",
      "event": "create",
      "time": "1530574195",
      "region": "CO"
      ...
  }
]
```

Kibana data in table format:-

[image: Kibana]

But when I see same data in JSON format in Kibana it display it correctly.

[image: kibana data in json format]

Can someone help with this ?  I am not able to plot correct graph as its taking as 4.99 and skipping rest if the parts .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can change that precision in the Advanced Settings tab in Management Section. The key could be the **format:number:defaultPattern**. You can learn more about the mask in this [link](http://numeraljs.com/).

Comment: I saw that but cound't find pattern for  1.1.1 like stuff because that is not number and I think when it is taking as number it is truncating last part.  So even I tried changing format of data to string "4.99.6" using logstash mutate covert but that also didn't help.

Comment: changing format:number:defaultPattern , gives different form of data but still not able to get desired result.  (4.99.6) its ignoring second decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Kibana 6.3.
I used 5.6 and I don't see any issue there.

I used 6.2 also and there is no issue. It seems only issue with 6.3.